# how to pass the parameter with spaces and access the same value in another page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to pass a value through url to access the same value in the next page. When i pass the value i can see in my url

> value=example+value

but when i use the following in views it then sends only the first part of the value after it pass to the next page.

```
 <%= link_to edit, edit_post_path(post, :value => params[:value]) %>
```

when the edit button is clicked it performs the action and when it goes to the next page i see only `value=example` in the url. what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way to do that is using permalinks… To do that, you have some [gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs) or you could see [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url) railscast to do it.